# Does C++ optimise construction-and-copy into a copy constructor?

Tags: c++

Does a C++ compiler automatically convert:

```
MyObject object2 = object1;
```

into

```
MyObject object2( object1 );
```

?

Or does it treat it like:

```
MyObject object2;
object2 = object1;
```

?

Comment: If it was a real performance problem, you'd probably already know the answer. In general, don't worry about micro-optimizations like this unless it's in a bottleneck and you've found it to cause a real problem. If you want to know whether a compiler does optimization X, assume that the answer is yes.

Comment: I guess I was also interested in best practice. Whether or not it is a micro optimisation depends a lot on the size of the object and the size/frequency of the function that creates it.

Comment: @PP - Yes, the degree that this might be an optimization _does_ depend on those things. Which is why you shouldn't bother optimizing unless you've profiled and found it to be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to see the exact behavior:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyObject {
public:
    MyObject() {
        std::cout << "MyObject()" << std::endl;
    }
    MyObject(const MyObject& other) {
        std::cout << "MyObject(const MyObject& other)" << std::endl;
    }
    MyObject& operator=(const MyObject& other) {
        std::cout << "operator=(const MyObject& other)" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyObject object1;
    MyObject object2 = object1;
    MyObject object3(object1);
    MyObject object4;
    object4 = object1;
}
```

Outputs:

```
MyObject()
MyObject(const MyObject& other)
MyObject(const MyObject& other)
MyObject()
operator=(const MyObject& other)
```

Apart from that, I recommend reading [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Thank you for the clear example code. As you can see some of the answers have conflicted. This leaves no doubt.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's the first one.  It's not an "optimisation"; they are two different syntaxes for invoking the copy constructor.

If you want to prove it, try defining a private assignment operator for `MyObject`.  The code should still compile, which proves it can't be equivalent to the second mechanism.

Comment: Is there some issue about explicit copy constructors, though?

Comment: @Kerrek: yes, the initialization with equals will not consider explicit constructors.

Comment: @Kerrek: Given `type a = b;` where the type of `b` is not `type`, that is transformed into an *implicit* conversion from `b` to `type` and copy constructor of `a` from the temporary (pseudo-coe): `type a( implicit_conversion<type>(b) );`. What Oli has stated is exactly correct: it is another syntax to invoke the *copy constructor* (not *any* constructor), and the implicit/explicit conversions only affect in as much as the argument might have to be converted before calling the copy constructor.

Comment: ... also note that there is not only the issue with explicitness of the constructor. Because the type is converted *before* calling the copy constructor, if the copy constructor cannot take an *rvalue* (i.e. if it is declared as: `type::type( type & );` --which is a valid signature), then it will also fail to compile. Again, the reason is that the syntax is in fact an alternative syntax for *copy construction*.

Comment: @David: So if `a` and `b` are of the same type, can I always say `type a = b;`, even if the copy constructor is explicit?

Answer (score 2):

What gets called with `MyObject object2 = object1;` is a constructor because this is initialization. This has nothing to do with the assignment operator.

However, the transformation you suggested from `MyObject object2 = object1;` into `MyObject object2(object1);` does not happen, because these two initialization syntaxes are not the same. They are similar in that they both initialize an object by calling a constructor, but they have a slight difference.

If you have:

```
struct MyObject {
    explicit MyObject(MyObject const&);
};
```

Then `MyObject object2 = object1;` is ill-formed, but `MyObject object2(object1);` is well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyObject object2 = object1;
```

is **copy-initialization**. This will call the copy constructor, if `object1` is of type `MyObject`.

If `object1` is of a different type then it will either do an implicit conversion from `object1` to `MyObject`, and then either copy-construct `object2` from that, or do the implicit conversion directly into `object2` and skip the copy construction. The copy constructor (or move constructor in C++11) must be accessible in both cases.

Comment: I don't think C++11 _requires_ the move constructor, does it?

Comment: To do copy initialization in C++11 then you must have either a copy or move constructor, or both.

Comment: Your last sentence implies that a move constructor must be accessible in C++11, just making sure it's clear what you meant.